# Increment within console.log changes value of variable

Tags: javascript, variables, console.log

I just ran into this:

```
let a = 1;
console.log(a++);
console.log(a); // 2
```

I am trying to understand how is the value of 'a' changed within console.log.

Comment: `a++` is the equivalent of running `a = a + 1`. Its value is being incremented in the first `console.log`.

Comment: I understand that but i didnt know this can be done in console.log

Comment: @Alinacdn - Calling `console.log` is just like calling any other function. `foo(a++)` would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's the basis of programming, pal. `x++` gets `x` and then increments it. `++x` first increments, then returns.

Comment: @T. J. Crowder  ok that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In a comment you've said:

> I understand [that `a++` is `a = a + 1`] but i didnt know this can be done in `console.log`

Calling `console.log` is just like calling any other function. `foo(a++)` would do exactly the same thing:

- First, the value of `a` is set aside for future use
- Then 1 is added to it, updating `a`
- Then the old value of `a` from Step 1 is passed to `foo` (or `console.log`).

(That's because you used postfix increment. If you'd used prefix increment [`++a`], the function would recieve the updated value, not the old value.)

`console.log` is not special, it's just a predefined function most environments (browsers, Node.js) make available to your code. If you perform side effects within its argument list (such as `a++`), those side effects occur.

Comment: you've answered my question! This is what I needed to understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

`a++` is like you would run it outside the console.log() it's just adding +1 to a

```js
let a = 1;
console.log(a++);
console.log(a); // 2
a++
console.log(a); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`a++` is the equivalent of `a = a + 1` happening after the variable a is evaluated.

Thus, you get 1 for the `console.log` statement and then a is incremented:

Your code could also be written as this, the `++` is just shorter:

```
let a = 1;
console.log(a);
a = a + 1;
console.log(a); // 2
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 0):

The example below shows two ways of incrementing the counter within a string.

Note the space before the slash in the first output.

```js
let i = 0;
let docNum = 10;

console.log('Document', i+1, '/' + docNum + '.')
// Document 1 /10.
console.log('Document ' + parseInt(i+1) + '/' + docNum + '.')
// Document 1/10.
```